# make my htacces that delete the parameter of the page to contain more page

Tags: php, .htaccess, parameters

i have problem to improve my htacces to contain more pages

, i have htacess that delete the parameter of Playlist.php?v=1 and convert it to Playlist/1

the real problem is i have more than Playlist page

i have 5 page more like Type.php,Videos.php,Watch.php

i tried to douple the same code in the htacces with different parameter but

nothing worked with me

my htacces code is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /PlayList\.php\?v=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /PlayList/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^PlayList/(\d+)/?$ PlayList.php?v=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regex alternation you will need only single rule rather than 4 rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(PlayList|Type|Videos|Watch)\.php\?v=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^(PlayList|Type|Videos|Watch)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?v=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: good :) thanks but could you change the code above ? in my question ? because i think its better than the one which i wrote above 
the could which i'm speaking about i toke it from you before :)

Comment: ok I have updated answer with full .htaccess that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the question by changing the code completely 
this is my so small solution

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^PlayList/([^/]*)$ /PlayList.php?v=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^Type/([^/]*)$ /Type.php?v=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^Videos/([^/]*)$ /Videos.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^Watch/([^/]*)$ /Watch.php?v=$1 [L]
```